# Structural break detection in time series

Tags: time-series, structural-change

I have the following timeseries of the electrical current consumption of a CNC milling machine.

[image]

My goal is to determine any breakpoints within the signal automatically, since I want to predict diffferent operating states in other timeseries similar to the depicted one. Of course I could do it manually, but in future the prediction shall be done online, so breakpoint detection has to be made automatically.

I already tried a CUSUM test within Matlab, which worked fine for the detection of the first breakpoint (see red line). I could reset the cumulative sum and start the CUSUM test from the detected breakpoint to find the next one, but the problem is to determine parameters for thresholds (climit), that fit in general. I doubt this approach will ever work, because the order of states, the machine will get into and therefore the patterns in the current consumption might be different between any of the other timseries.

So my question is, is there a better approach or method for detecting multiple structural breaks within a timeseries like the one above without having to worry too much about the robustness of the break detetction?

Comment: Try impulse indicator saturation by David Hendry et al., e.g. [here](http://mitpress.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.7551/mitpress/9780262028356.001.0001/upso-9780262028356-chapter-20).